# Cakephp 3.6.14: Reload BootstrapTable content after ajax-form submission with new content

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, cakephp, bootstrap-table

I have a form in a modal which adds new rows to a `BootstrapTable`. I want the table to be reloaded after successful form submission without reloading the whole page.

I tried that:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

But is not working. How I can achieve what I want?

This is the `BootstrapTable`:

```
<table class="table-striped" id="table" data-toggle="table"
                         data-search="true"
                         data-filter-control="true"
                         data-click-to-select="true"
                         data-escape="false"
                         >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="linksSorter" scope="col"><?= __('Title') ?></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($tasks as $task):
                            <tr>
                                 <td><?= $task->has('name') ? $this->Html->link($task->name, ['controller' => 'Tasks', 'action' => 'edit', $task->id], ['data-target' => '#exampleFormModal', 'data-toggle'=>'modal']) : '' ?></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php endif;
                         endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

This is the `jquery` code for the form submission:

```
$(function () {
    $("#DAbtn").click(function () { //Direct Assign button

        //e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "btn").val("Direct Assign");
        $('#newTaskForm').append(input);
        var task = $("#newTaskForm").serialize();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/app/tasks/createTask',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: task,
            success: function( data )
            {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
                $("#newTaskForm")[0].reset();
                clearForm("newTaskForm");

                $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

And here is the controller code (createTask function):

```
public function createTask($userid = null, $projectid = null, $copiedtaskid = null)
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $http = new Client();


        $task = $this->Tasks->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {  
             //....code to create the task......
        }
        $this->response->statusCode(200);
        return $this->response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I perform my ajax-form submissions:

1.
Place your `BootstrapTable` code in an element.

2.
In your classical view, you need to call the new created element to have the `BootstrapTable` displayed (with the proper $argumentsArray). Enclose with a tag for later ajax use:

```
echo '<div id="container">'.$this->Element('element_name', $argumentsArray).'</div>';
```

3.
Make sure your controller `createTask` function returns what is needed for your element. For example, you'll need

```
$this->set('tasks', $tasks);
```

You'll also need it to render to your element:

```
$this->render('element_name', 'ajax');
```

4.
Replace in your ajax success case:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

by

```
$('#container').html(data);
```

Comment: didn't manage to make it work... I get an error that createTask is missing template. Which is ok because there is no template for createTask, it just saves the form data and return a json object with the new table contents.